# How can I add a tabbed separator to pandas dataframe rows and save the output to a file?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I am trying to apply a tab as a separator to the dataframe before saving, but something wonky is happening with the Day of Week column?  Any ideas? Is there an easier approach using some type of fixed-width columns instead? Thanks!

```
entries = [{test_columns[index][0]:column for index, column in enumerate(value)} for value in test_cursor.fetchall()]
results = pd.DataFrame(entries)
results = results[['Test','Day of Week','Test Date','Number']]
results.to_csv('file.txt', sep='\t', index=False, header=False)
```

Current Output:

```
VERSCH  Tuesday 07/05/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Tuesday 07/05/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Tuesday 07/05/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Wednesday       07/06/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Wednesday       07/06/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Wednesday       07/06/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Thursday        07/07/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Thursday        07/07/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Thursday        07/07/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Thursday        07/07/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Friday  07/08/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Friday  07/08/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Monday  07/11/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Monday  07/11/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Monday  07/11/2016      3333333333
```

Desired Output:

```
VERSCH  Tuesday         07/05/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Tuesday         07/05/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Tuesday         07/05/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Wednesday       07/06/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Wednesday       07/06/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Wednesday       07/06/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Thursday        07/07/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Thursday        07/07/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Thursday        07/07/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Thursday        07/07/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Friday          07/08/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Friday          07/08/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Monday          07/11/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Monday          07/11/2016      3333333333
VERSCH  Monday          07/11/2016      3333333333
```

Comment: Is your goal that it looks pretty in text?  Or do you want it to look pretty in some other application that will be utilizing this output?  Because what you're seeing is correct.  tabs act funny when they are printed and look different depending on where they are displayed.  In this case, they are predefined tab stops, meaning there are display related columns that tabs should stop at.  The tab after Tuesday stops one column later, but Wednesday passes that one so stops at the next one.  This translates to un appealing output.

Comment: Ultimately, a standard output that can be used by another application.  I think fixed column widths would work much better, but I was having trouble getting consistent output with that either.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a string formatter:

```
str_fmt = "{Test:<10s}  {Day of Week:<10s}  {Test Date:>10s}  {Number:>10s}"
print results \
        .apply(lambda x: str_fmt.format(**x.to_dict()), axis=1) \
        .to_frame().to_csv(header=None, index=None)

VERSCH      Tuesday     07/05/2016  3333333333
VERSCH      Tuesday     07/05/2016  3333333333
VERSCH      Tuesday     07/05/2016  3333333333
VERSCH      Wednesday   07/06/2016  3333333333
VERSCH      Wednesday   07/06/2016  3333333333
VERSCH      Wednesday   07/06/2016  3333333333
VERSCH      Thursday    07/07/2016  3333333333
VERSCH      Thursday    07/07/2016  3333333333
VERSCH      Thursday    07/07/2016  3333333333
VERSCH      Thursday    07/07/2016  3333333333
VERSCH      Friday      07/08/2016  3333333333
VERSCH      Friday      07/08/2016  3333333333
VERSCH      Monday      07/11/2016  3333333333
VERSCH      Monday      07/11/2016  3333333333
VERSCH      Monday      07/11/2016  3333333333
```

Comment: I had tried this as well.  Maybe I should ask:  How can I get the Day of week column to always be 9 char long instead of varied?

Comment: I think I'm almost there, but I"m getting this error:  "ValueError: ("Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'", u'occurred at index 0')"

Comment: @Mike that's because we're trying to format  string as if it were a float.  I'd assumed `333333333` was a float.  I'll post some things to do to fix that.

Comment: Thank you!  The problem now is that if I try to save that to a file, the formatting is lost:  >> results.to_csv('test.txt', sep=' ', index=False, header=False)

Comment: I gave you the `to_csv` call.  Just add a `'text.txt'` as the first argument.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
   df["Day"] = df["Day"].str.pad(10, side='left', fillchar=' ')
   print df["Day"].head()

    0       Tuesday
    1       Tuesday
    2       Tuesday
    3     Wednesday
    4     Wednesday
    Name: Day, dtype: object

    print df

         Test         Day      Test.1      Number
    0   VERSCH     Tuesday  07/05/2016  3333333333
    1   VERSCH     Tuesday  07/05/2016  3333333333
    2   VERSCH     Tuesday  07/05/2016  3333333333
    3   VERSCH   Wednesday  07/06/2016  3333333333
    4   VERSCH   Wednesday  07/06/2016  3333333333
    5   VERSCH   Wednesday  07/06/2016  3333333333
    6   VERSCH    Thursday  07/07/2016  3333333333
    7   VERSCH    Thursday  07/07/2016  3333333333
    8   VERSCH    Thursday  07/07/2016  3333333333
    9   VERSCH    Thursday  07/07/2016  3333333333
    10  VERSCH      Friday  07/08/2016  3333333333
    11  VERSCH      Friday  07/08/2016  3333333333
    12  VERSCH      Monday  07/11/2016  3333333333
    13  VERSCH      Monday  07/11/2016  3333333333
    14  VERSCH      Monday  07/11/2016  3333333333
```